# Selecting specific row from database .net core 2

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I want to retrieve a specific row from the database.
so I'm using this command to retrieve it :

```
 UserOwner userowner =_context.User.FromSql("SELECT * FROM db.user WHERE name = 'username'").FirstOrDefault();
                return Ok(user);
```

the thing is this returns a list and I return the first on the list, but isn't there a way to return straight from the SQL command one row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try use labda function on FirstOrDefault.

```
UserOwner userowner =_context.User.FirstOrDefault(o=> o.name == "username" );
                return Ok(user);
```

but if you need use an SQL script, for MYSQL use:

```
"SELECT * FROM db.user WHERE name = 'username' LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do this using a "with" clause to get all of the rows and add a counter/index column then add a where clause to get the specific row.  This would give you the 5th row from the original query.

```
with mainqry as (select t.*, rownum as myindex from db.user t where t.name ='username') select * from mainqry q where q.myindex=5;
```